# Reformulating a problem as graph theoretic problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Reformulate the exercise as graph theoretical problem:
>
> Given a set $A$ with $n$ elements and $B={A₁,A₂,…,A_n}⊆2^A$. Prove that there exists an injective mapping $f:B→A$ such that $f(Aᵢ)∈Aᵢ$ for all $i∈1,2,…,n$ if and only if for all $I⊆{1,2,…,n}$ the cardinality of $⋃_{i∈I}Aᵢ$ is at least equal to the cardinality of $I$.

**My solution:**

We construct a bipartite graph by placing a node for every set $Aᵢ$ on the left side. Then we place a node for every element of $A$ on the right side. We connect a node for a certain set $Aᵢ$ with every node which contains an element of $Aᵢ$ with an undirected edge. To get an injective mapping we need to select a complete matching. This is the same task as in the marriage theorem. The elements of the set $A$ represent the men, while $A_i$ represents the set that woman $i$ is willing to marry. So to get to a complete matching all unions of the form $⋃_{i∈I}Aᵢ$ must be greater or equal to the number of sets in the union $I$.

To make things clearer we give a small example where we can construct an injective mapping:

$A=\{1,2,3\}$

$B=\{A₁,A₂,A₃\}⊆2^A$ e.g. $B=\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\}\}$

$f(A₁)∈A₁f(A₂)∈A₂,f(A₃)∈A₃$

The figure below shows the injective mapping for this example.

[image]

*Is this a sufficient proof, what can be changed or improved?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve correctly understood what’s going on, but you haven’t completely translated the exercise into graph-theoretic terms. You’ve described the right bipartite graph and correctly translated the injection into a matching for that graph, but you’ve not translated the condition following *if and only if*. That condition says that if $V_B$ is the vertex set corresponding to $B$, and $V_A$ is the vertex set corresponding to $A$, then for each $U\subseteq V_B$ we have $|U|\le|N(U)|$, where $N(U)$ is the neighborhood of $U$ (i.e., the set of vertices that are adjacent to at least one vertex in $U$).

Comment: Is this Hall's marriage theorem? Can you also explain that last part a bit more, I didn't exactly get it. On the other hand, to finish the problem, I just need to include the part that you wrote (nothing else to change)?

Comment: @portal: Yes, it’s a version of Hall’s marriage theorem. And yes, about all that you were missing is the bit that I wrote out.

Comment: One more question just to be clear, if we use my graph above, then for example, if I take $U$ to be $\{1,2\}$, then, for $N(U)$, I have the vertexes on the right named $1$, and $2$, right? So, I have $|U| = 1 \leq 2 = |N(U)|$.

Comment: When you are free can you also please take a look at this question, please? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511777/reformulating-a-problem-as-graph-theoretic

Comment: @portal: Yes, that’s right for the neighborhood. I’ll take a look at the other problem.

Comment: Thank you once more Brian!